# Trying to stop a timeout function with jQuery

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-selectors

I have a set of absolutely positioned divs which are containers for images. Each div has a class of `photoCover` and each img has a class of `fbPhoto`. I have setup a looping function which on page load fades each image in the collection out, thus revealing the one below and then loops.

What I need though to be able to stop this when a user clicks any of these.

I've tried various options involving `$(this).stop(true, true)` and several examples on SO but nothing seems to work.

Here's the code for the loop function

```
var thumbNailTimeOut;
function loopSmallSlides(eleArray) {
    var slideCount = eleArray.length;
    $(eleArray).each(function (indexInArray) {
        var ele = this;
        thumbNailTimeOut = setTimeout(function () {
            if (indexInArray == slideCount - 1) {
                $(eleArray).fadeIn('slow').on("click", function () {
                    clearTimeout(thumbNailTimeOut);
                }); 
                clearTimeout(thumbNailTimeOut);
                loopSmallSlides(eleArray); // loop the function when the end is reached
            } else {
                $(ele).fadeToggle('slow').on("click", function () {
                    clearTimeout(thumbNailTimeOut);
                }); 
            };
        }, (indexInArray + 1) * 1000);
    });
};
```

The loop function accepts an array of elements generated on `document.ready` as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.photoCover').each(function () {
        // get an array of elements to slide
        var eleArray = $(this).children('.fbPhoto').get().reverse();
        loopSmallSlides(eleArray);
    });
});
```

The snippet

```
$(ele).fadeToggle('slow').on("click", function () {
    clearTimeout(thumbNailTimeOut);
});
```

is attempting to add a click handler to each element within the array such that it will clear the timeout when any of these elements are clicked, but it isn't working. As you can see the variable `thumbNailTimeOut` is a globally available variable... this as far as I understand *should* work to cancel that `timeOut`?

As mentioned I have tried using `stop` but can't get anywhere, I tried adding a `click` to the parent element and then looping through the children removing any animations as below, but that doesn't work.

```
$('.photoCover').each(function () {
     $(this).children('.fbPhoto').stop(true, true);
});
```

The HTML if needed looks like:

```
<style>
   .photoCover{display:inline-block;width:204px;height:194px;vertical-align:top;}
   .fbPhoto{position:absolute;display:inline-block;width:110px;height:110px;margin:4px;background-position:center center;background-repeat:no-repeat;border-radius:5px;border:16px groove #93BABA;background-color:#93BABA;}
</style>

<div class="photoCover">
   <h4>Album Title</h4>                     
   <span style="background-image: url('IMG URL');" class="fbPhoto"></span>
   <span style="background-image: url(IMG URL); " class="fbPhoto"></span>
   <span style="background-image: url(IMG URL); " class="fbPhoto"></span>
   <span style="background-image: url(IMG URL); " class="fbPhoto"></span>
   <span style="background-image: url(IMG URL); " class="fbPhoto"></span>                        
</div>
```

So my question is, having set this loop up on each set of images nested within the parent `.photoCover` element, how can I pause that animation with a click and then restart too?

Any help much appreciated! It seems lots of other questions exist on SO about this, but I can't get the answers to work for this example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thumbNailTimeOut is being overwritten over and over again in this function:

```
$(eleArray).each(function (indexInArray) { /* fn body */ });
```

After the function has finished its work, the only thing that is stored in your variable is the last one of the timeouts you have set. You could try using your variable as an array. For example:

```
thumbNailTimeOut[index] = setTimeout(function () { /* fn body */ }, delay);
```

Clearing the timeout would become:

```
clearTimeout(thumbNailTimeOut[index]);
```

But to be honest: I don't like your approach of using that many timeouts. Maybe using a single interval function would be far more convenient.

**EDIT:**
I tried to rewrite your function with an interval. I haven't tried it yet but it looks a lot cleaner than the timeout code:

```
function loopSmallSlides(eleArray) {
    var interval
    ,   $elems = $(eleArray);
    ,   current = 0;
    ,   slideCount = eleArray.length;

    interval = setInterval(function(){
        current = intervalFn($elems, current);
    }, 1000);

    $elems.on('click', function(e) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    });
};

function intervalFn($elems, current) {
    if( current < $elems.length) {
        $elems.eq(current).fadeIn('slow');
        return current+1;
    } else {
        $elems.fadeOut('slow');
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Took a bit of fiddling to complete the whole thing, but that worked nicely! :)